# log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile) in production

Tags: go, logging

Is it good practice (at least general practice) to have `log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)` in production in Go? I wonder if there is whether performance or security issue by doing it in production. Since it is not default setting of `log` package in Go. Still can't find any official reference or even opinion article regarding that matter.

Comment: I've never actually seen the stdlib `log` package used in production code at all (except where it's necessary to interact with some library that expects a `*log.Logger`--and then it's a simple wrapper), so based on my own (very unscientific) sample size, common practice doesn't even have this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, so how the way you have some kind of monitoring or detect any possibility of errors in your app? Currently, the way I am doing is by logging errors which may occur to stdout/stderr ( I am working in Kubernetes ), then there is "Log collector" named "Fluentd" which will aggregating logs in all apps including error messages.

Comment: I use a logger, just not the one from the stdlib, which is very inflexible. I've worked on projects that use logrus, zerolog, and a small number of other, less popular options.

Comment: My [_personal opinion_](https://jhall.io/posts/6-logging-mistakes/) is that whatever logging library you use must allow for changing or adding backends transparently to the code--even if most of your logs ultimately go to stderr.

Comment: I see, actually, I had used logrus previously, but I feel the way it showing filename and line number of code in the log ( when debugging in dev ), not natural compared to stdlib. Especially it is wont to work nicely with my IDE ( Goland ), while in stdlib logger, the log output treated as a "reference" by Goland, I just click on the log output and Goland will get me the file opened in the IDE and focus on exactly line number where the log is written. Do you have any trick regarding logrus and IDE integration like that mentioned above?

Comment: You have complete control over how logrus formats logs. I don't think I've ever used it to log line numbers (except in stack traces). Anyway, this is getting way out of scope for comments. If you're interested in a longer chat, maybe we can open a chat.

Comment: I mean I did log line numbers when debugging :). log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile) will show filename of code and line number in front of our logs. In logrus, I had this previously: https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues/63#issuecomment-476486166

Answer (score 4):

As for the performance. Yes, it has an impact, however, it is imho negligible for various reasons.

### Testing

#### Code

```golang
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkStdLog(b *testing.B) {
    // We do not want to benchmark the shell
    stdlog := log.New(ioutil.Discard, "", log.LstdFlags)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        stdlog.Println("foo")
    }
}

func BenchmarkShortfile(b *testing.B) {
    slog := log.New(ioutil.Discard, "", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        slog.Println("foo")
    }
}
```

#### Result

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: stackoverflow.com/go/logbench
BenchmarkStdLog-4        3803840           277 ns/op           4 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkShortfile-4     1000000          1008 ns/op         224 B/op          3 allocs/op
```

Your mileage may vary, but the order of magnitude should be roughly equal.

### Why I think the impact is negligible

It is unlikely that your logging will be the bottleneck of your application, unless you write a shitload of logs. In 99 times out of 100, it is not the logging which is the bottleneck.

Get your application up and running, load test and profile it. You can still optimize then.

Hint: make sure you can scale out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed and clear answer. Do you think it is a good practice / general practice doing it in production based on your experience? I just a remote worker who has not many programmer friends to know how people programming :). TBH, I just afraid if it only me who did that in the world LOL :D

Comment: I'd personally only use it for debugging purposes: https://play.golang.org/p/Ehmkd8V_wm4

Comment: Looks like the same  on my current app, just using a different approach which uses ``if os.GetEnv("GO_ENV") == "development"``. Just thinking how hard tracing log in production when we found an error log without knowing which file and which line. Looks like it should be that way :). Thanks again for your reply.